# How do I get node.js to return pages without file extensions?

Tags: node.js, routes, express

Right now, any static html will get server as is (about.html, work.html, etc) using

```
app.use express.static("#{__dirname}/app")
```

How do I tell it to return the same file with just "about"?

Answer (score 3):

`express.static` actually comes from [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect), on which Express is built.  If you look at [the source of the static middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js), you'll see that it's relatively simple, since the real logic has been abstracted out to the [send](https://npmjs.org/package/send) module.

The baked-in static middleware cannot do what you're trying to accomplish, but it would be simple enough to tweak it into your own:

```
var send = require('./node_modules/express/node_modules/send') // grab the npm-installed send module that comes with express
    , utils = require('.node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils') // ...and connect's utils
    , parse = utils.parseUrl
    , url = require('url');


function customStatic(root, options){
    options = options || {};

    // root required
    if (!root) throw new Error('static() root path required');

    // note: I've stripped out directory redirection
    // (ie, redirecting from /somefolder to /somefolder/)
    // because appending an extension logically makes that code unreachable

    return function(req, res, next) {
        if ('GET' != req.method && 'HEAD' != req.method) return next();
        var path = parse(req).pathname
            , filename = pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf('/')); // the part of the URL after the last slash, excluding the query string

        // and finally, the reason we're here: if the filename has no extension, append one
        if (options.defaultExtension && filename.indexOf('.') == -1) path += '.' + options.defaultExtension;

        var pause = utils.pause(req);

        function resume() {
            next();
            pause.resume();
        }

        function error(err) {
            if (404 == err.status) return resume();
            next(err);
        }

        send(req, path)
            .maxage(options.maxAge || 0)
            .root(root)
            .index(options.index || 'index.html')
            .hidden(options.hidden)
            .on('error', error)
            .pipe(res);
    };
};
```

Then use it just like the Connect's static module:

```
app.use(customStatic(__dirname + '/app', { defaultExtension: 'html' }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Express' `res.sendfile`. A basic example:

```
app.get('/:file', function (req, res) {
    var file = req.params.file;

    res.sendfile('app/' + file + '.html');

});
```